How to Improve Adhesion of Velcro to Plastic Suction Cups in Hot Climates
I am currently facing an issue with a product where Velcro is attached to plastic suction cups using adhesive. The Velcro tends to detach from the suction cups, especially in hot climates. Here are some details:


Materials: Velcro and plastic suction cups.
Current Adhesive: The existing adhesive does not hold up well under high temperatures.
Problem: The bond between the Velcro and the suction cup weakens, causing the Velcro to fall off.

I am looking for recommendations on:

Suitable Adhesives: What types of adhesives would provide a durable and heat-resistant bond for this application?
Application Methods: What is the best way to apply the adhesive to ensure maximum adhesion and longevity?
Testing Procedures: How can I test the bond strength and heat resistance of the adhesive to ensure it will perform well in hot climates?

Additionally, if there are alternative methods for securely attaching Velcro to plastic suction cups, I would be interested in hearing those as well.
Thank you for your assistance!
